# ASP.NET Core unit test throws Null Exception when testing controller problem response

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm creating basic unit tests for my project. For some reason, I keep getting a NullReferenceException when testing that I get a `ControllerBase.Problem(String, String, Nullable<Int32>, String, String)` response. I'm sure the problem is a discrepancy from the controller not actually running, as it seems to behave perfectly fine when the controller is running.

Controller:

```cs
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        [Produces("application/json")]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
        public IActionResult GetPatient([GuidNotEmpty] Guid id)
        {
            Patient patient = null;

            patient = _patientDbService.FindPatient(id);
            if (patient == null) {
                return Problem("Patient not found.", string.Empty, StatusCodes.Status404NotFound,
                    "An error occurred.", "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1");
            }

            return Ok(patient);
        }
```

Test:

```cs
        [Fact]
        public void TestGetPatientFromIdPatientNotFound()

        {
            // Act
            IActionResult result = _patientController.GetPatient(Guid.NewGuid());

            // Assert
            Assert.IsType<ObjectResult>(result);
            Assert.NotNull(((ObjectResult)result).Value);
            Assert.IsType<ProblemDetails>(((ObjectResult)result).Value);
            Assert.Equal(((ObjectResult)result).StatusCode, StatusCodes.Status404NotFound);
        }
```

Result:

```
X PatientServiceTest.PatientServiceUnitTest.TestGetPatientFromIdPatientNotFound [1ms]
Error Message:
   System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Stack Trace:
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerBase.Problem(String detail, String instance, Nullable`1 statusCode, String title, String type)
   at PatientService.Controllers.PatientController.GetPatient(Guid id) in /home/surafel/coding/microservices-dev/c#/PatientService/Controllers/PatientController.cs:line 43
   at PatientServiceTest.PatientServiceUnitTest.TestGetPatientFromIdPatientNotFound() in /home/surafel/coding/microservices-dev/c#/PatientServiceTest/PatientServiceUnitTest.cs:line 69
```

Comment: How have you initialized `_patientController`? How are you specifying its dependencies? `ControllerBase` relies on various framework level services.

Comment: I don't know much about this. But If I were you i'll
1. Try to debug the test and check variables
2. Remove all arguments to the Problem statement or event change to Ok
May not resolve the problem but can help tracing the problem.
Testing controllers is a little difficult as mentioned above by @AluanHaddad , it relies on a lot of other stuff

Comment: I'm specifying it's dependencies. I mocked the db service I used, and I haven't had any problems with it until now. I used to test for `BadRequestObjectResult` instead of just `ObjectResult`.

Comment: Here's the reason: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ControllerBase.cs#L194

Comment: What would be the standard way for fixing this? I wanted to have a consistent structure for my errors. Would encapsulating the `Problem` call in a try-catch loop, and create my own `ProblemDetails` be a proper solution?

Comment: That would be a very bad idea. If you want to test controllers, you really need to mock the HTTP request pipeline. [Microsoft has a controller testing guide here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/testing?view=aspnetcore-3.1). Additionally, I recommend that you keep controller tests to a minimum by keeping your controllers as free as business logic as possible.

Comment: Wouldn't unit tests be used to ensure that the controller and the business logic behave correctly? Also the link you gave me doesn't have information to how to mock the ProblemDetailsFactory?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As pointed out by Aluan Haddad in the comments, the that `Problem()` calls `ProblemDetailsFactory` to create the `ProblemDetails` objects, which is supplied by the service manager. The service manager only works when the application is running:https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ControllerBase.cs#L194

The `ControllerBase.ProblemDetailsFactory` variable can be set, so I created a mock `ProblemDetailsFactory` instance and set the controllers factory to an instance of my mock. This seems to make it work.

Mock:

```cs
    public class MockProblemDetailsFactory : ProblemDetailsFactory
    {
        public MockProblemDetailsFactory()
        {
        }

        public override ProblemDetails CreateProblemDetails(HttpContext httpContext,
            int? statusCode = default, string title = default,
            string type = default, string detail = default, string instance = default)
        {
            return new ProblemDetails() {
                Detail = detail,
                Instance = instance,
                Status = statusCode,
                Title = title,
                Type = type,
            };
        }

        public override ValidationProblemDetails CreateValidationProblemDetails(HttpContext httpContext,
            ModelStateDictionary modelStateDictionary, int? statusCode = default,
            string title = default, string type = default, string detail = default,
            string instance = default)
        {
            return new ValidationProblemDetails(new Dictionary<string, string[]>()) {
                Detail = detail,
                Instance = instance,
                Status = statusCode,
                Title = title,
                Type = type,
            };
        }
    }
```

I added this line in the setup for this unit tests, and it solves the problem.

```cs
_patientController.ProblemDetailsFactory = new MockProblemDetailsFactory();
```

Comment: This is functional but really disappointing from an ergonomics perspective